# Unknown namespace: "sap.ui.core.mvc" - UI5 Language Assistant

Tags: sapui5

Can someone help me with this error? What should I do?

[image: UI5 language assistant error "sap.ui.core.mvc" unknown]

Comment: Is the issue still reproducible after updating the _UI5 Language Assistant_ extension?

Comment: I made the same way in the link. I downloaded VSIX and then everything is good tell now. I wanted to ask you, can you advise me good free  course for sapui5, but not from channel freecodecamp, I watched it but did not understand from him. Maybe I become job in the next days as sapui5 developer and I have to learn the basics. Thank you

Comment: That confirms that installing the _UI5 Language Assistant_ extension officially from the marketplace will also resolve the issue since the extension from the marketplace also contains the latest changes. Please remove the manually added extension and install it from the marketplace

Comment: Regarding "free course"; I guess by "course" you mean video tutorials? In that case, take a look at the ["2 Minutes of UI5"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9NMwsipMkw&list=PLHUs_FUbq4dUupZMsC9AJtJf2nTsxrI1Y) as a starting point and let me / us (community) know how it was. I personally recommend jumping right away to the [Walkthrough](https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/#/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db) from the OpenUI5 documentation but that might be a bit dry for other people.

Comment: PS: the openSAP course ["Developing and Extending SAP Fiori Elements Apps"](https://open.sap.com/courses/fiori-ea1) is also fairly up-to-date and freely available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been reported at https://github.com/SAP/ui5-language-assistant/issues/487 as well as same question asked at [Warning "Unkown namespace: sap.ui.core.mvc" - how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73556081/warning-unkown-namespace-sap-ui-core-mvc-how-to-fix-it)

The *UI5 Language Assistant* extension from the VSCode marketplace should contain several [important fixes and enhancements](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-language-assistant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) [by now](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SAPOSS.vscode-ui5-language-assistant). Simply update the extension and restart VSCode.